# Program to automatically complete surveys

Tags: survey

I am looking for a program that can

- automatically complete surveys from surveymonkey.com, using random answers

I would prefer if

- it runs on Windows 7, but Ubuntu or Mac is fine too.
- supports other survey platforms too
- free

Comment: Do you mean, randomly? Or using a file containing answers to each question?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul randomly

Comment: sneaky sneaky sneaky ;p. Do you mind scripting it per survey?

Comment: If it wouldn't be you, but a "first time poster", I'd think of "bad intentions". To instead give a "good example", mind specifying some background (aka "user story")? Otherwise readers might think it's OK to ask for "manipulation tools" of any kind ;)

Comment: I have to agree, I find this sort of request rather inappropriate. I'm definitely open to the possibility that there could be a legitimate and ethical reason for doing this, but without said reason being stated it just doesn't seem proper.

Comment: When I get spam repeatedly to fill a survey, I spam the survey. Nature law! So I'm fighting spam. Anyone want to help? :)

Comment: I see no problem with the question! Say that the OP asked for a recommendation of software that would send out surveys.  Some people feel that it's unethical (or, perhaps, immoral) to send unsolicited communications, but I don't think it would be proper for them to criticize the question.  Please don't get me wrong; I applaud a strong sense of ethics and morality, and it impresses me when someone cares enough to act on it :)

Comment: You can find some help here : http://css-tricks.com/prefilling-forms-custom-bookmarklet/ , I used to do it for my own forms , surveys are forms right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a software testing technique called 'fuzzing' or '[fuzz testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing)' that bombards the software under test with a bunch of random inputs.

This instructive article might be helpful:
http://lifeofpentester.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/fuzz-testing-web-applications-with-burp.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use python & the [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) library to do this sort of thing providing the field names/IDs are consistent, i.e. you are filling in the form on a single site.

Some useful examples [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet).